# How can you use variable for the path argument for the Unix find command?

Tags: linux, unix, variables, path, find

Unix command find doesn't do what I want to do.
Here is the situation

If I type:
`find ../tmp -name "\*tmp\*"`

it correctly outputs the files that contain "tmp" in its name in tmp folder

but when I type:

```
dir=../tmp #assign ../tmp as a variable named dir

find ${dir} -name "\*tmp\*"
```

the output says:  No such file or directory

My guess is that the find command assumes that the variable "dir" as a file to look for?
How can I go around this problem? 
The reason I want to know this is so that I can pass the path as an argument for my script.
Thanks

-----------Additional comment

I use the bash shell.
Sorry for the confusion. The above code works. The real problem is when I incorporate {} structure in the variable. For example,
When I type

dir=../{tmp1,tmp3} #assign ../{tmp1,tmp3} as a variable named dir

find ${dir} -name "*tmp*"

the output says:  No such file or directory
Why??

Comment: What you posted *ought* to work.  Can you give a more exact list of commands you typed and the exact results? Which shell are you using?

Comment: What you typed works for me. You should get exactly the same output whether you use the variable expension `${dir}` or the literal string `../tmp`. Are you sure there is not something different in how&when you're invoking the two commands? Is your current working directory the same in both cases?

Comment: What shell are you using?  tcsh?  bash?  ksh?  Probably bash, but please be specific.  Different shells have different ways of assigning variables.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line is evaluated command-wise first and then any action (like setting environment variables, calling programms) is done. Therefore  $dir is set not before the command line is evaluated. One possibility to solve the problem is to separate the variable setting from its usage by `;`

```
dir=../tmp ; find "$dir" -name "tmp"
```

or to write the commands into two separate lines (Thiruvalluvar's answer).

```
dir=../tmp
find "$dir" -name "tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

(From the command line)

```
# dir="../tmp/whatever/your/directory"
# find $dir -name "*tmp*"
```